# String formation to independent variables

Tags: python, string

```
String = 'var1 = hello, var2 = bye'
```

So i have this string that is being returned from a webpage and im trying to turn this into this:

```
   var1 = 'Hello'
   var2 = 'bye'
```

I was wondering if this could be done using .format or something else.

> one of my biggest problem is time, i want the fasted method.

Comment: I smell an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: No, you do *not* want to create variable variables from a string, and no, `.format` won't get you anywhere near it.

Comment: @deceze is right, however he's not telling you that you CAN do that using f-strings and walrus. It's a bad practice for sure...but you CAN xD

Comment: @Gameplay Err, please clarify how f-strings and walruses help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a `dictionary` to store `key` value `pair`

```
data = 'var1 = hello, var2 = bye' # the data returned from a web page

dmap = {}

for value in data.split(","):
    array = value.split("=")
    dmap[array[0].strip()] = array[1].strip()

print(dmap)
```

Comment: FWIW, a one-liner: `d = dict(map(str.strip, i.split('=')) for i in data.split(','))`.

Comment: Except for the fact that `dmap` is pretty bad and non-descriptive name for anything it's all good 

Comment: Forget my previous comment, the oneliner is way worse ‍♂️ I hope that during the code review that would get rejected.

Comment: @CoolGuy Please provide the `String` value on which you are working because the above expression is for `string` data in this particular format 'var1 = val1, var2 = val2, var3 = val3, varn = valn'

Comment: @devp I apologies the problem I had was that there was a ``,``  at the start of my string which is why I got that error. Thank you for your respond and your answer.